# C2DM with App engine

Tags: google-app-engine, android-c2dm

I am constructing an application and planning to use C2DM with app engine running on my application server, I am wondering is their a sample project or tutorial online that involves using C2DM and App engine, I have tried googleing but I cannot find what I'm looking for

All the best and thanks in Advance,
Matt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try the official documentation?

There is [an example](https://developers.google.com/android/c2dm/#example) that runs on GAE.